# Objective-C Set variables in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why people write:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
object.somePreperty = view;
```

instead of

```
object.someProperty = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Comment: It is like asking, why do some people prefere tea over coffee. There is no particular answer. Both codes above written are serving the same purpose.

Comment: Actually, they're not the same. One constructs a UIView and then sets a property on that view — the other initialises an existing view's property to a newly constructed UIView.

Comment: Property references itself???

Comment: @Andrew, I think that is a typo from him. `view.somePreperty = view;` should be `view1.somePreperty = view;` or so. Otherwise there is no point in this question.

Comment: sorry, of course it's not references itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the usage of the alloc sources from the pre ARC world requiring full memory management. That is, the code used to look like this often:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
object.property = view;
[view release];
```

Comment: +1 Kevin. But now(ARC) it's just coding style.

Comment: Which is still pretty rediculous considering that the vast majority of object properties are strong, thus requiring a release and nil-ing out in dealloc.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two reasons:

- For the sake of debugging, so we can check the `view` instance before assigning it to the property.
- `view` might need some more initialisation other than just `init`, e.g. setFrame.

Personally, I always assign to local variable first for fancy objects. If it's just small array or dictionary, I assign directly.